# Open and pick a contact from a device contact app

Tags: java, codenameone

I am building an invitation form in which the user can fill an email or use a button that will open a contact app in his device and will get the email of a chosen contact(if email exists). I wonder if this kind of button is possible to achieve in Codename One **without listing all the user's contacts in my app**.

Thanks!

Itay

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/contacts/ContactsManager.html), you may only use `id` to retrieve a certain contact using method [getContactById(String id)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/contacts/ContactsManager.html#getContactById-java.lang.String-).

So, the answer is "No", you cannot get the contact by its email since you don't know the mapping `id <> email`

Comment: Notice you can use `getContactById(String id, boolean includesFullName, 
boolean includesPicture, boolean includesNumbers, boolean includesEmail,boolean includeAddress)` and pass false for everything other than email which should fetch the contact relatively quickly without fetching all the data. The same would work for `Contact[] getAllContacts(boolean withNumbers, boolean includesFullName, boolean includesPicture, boolean includesNumbers, boolean includesEmail, boolean includeAddress)`